# Error with attaching file in Mozilla 24.0

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, mozilla

Early code had worked fine in all browsers. After updating to the new version of Mozilla got out error. In google I found only one link about this - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=796850, and I don't understand, how to get rid of problems.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert string to ByteString because the character at index 0 has value 1054 which is greater than 255.
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
```

In this code:

```
....
xhr.open('POST', get_page_url() + '?operation=upload_files');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
xhr.send(file);
...
```

In `file.name` normal cyrillic file name with the extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved problem:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
```

Replaced to..

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", unescape(encodeURIComponent(file.name)));
```